# What would be a good way to implement a grid in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am wanting to edit a number of rows in a model in a grid. I would really like to be able to edit "inline" ie within the grid rather than going off to another page via another controller.

I know about the "Web Grid" which seems lean, but I believe it needs to go over to an edit page.

In the first instance I am wanting to focus on server solutions for simplicity. Also I would want the control to respect the validation data annotations in the View Model.

Many thanks,

Ed

Comment: Can you use the knockoutjs framework? It's pretty easy and light-weight way to connect the model on the page with the DOM. You can just use the regular table tag and still implement what you want. Please look onto this sample: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/contactsEditor.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render your own grid for a table of data and include a form within it to allow the user to edit a particular row. You will need to implement typical grid features to control this process, such as row selection, insert, edit, update and possibly delete. There are plenty of good models from Web Forms world you could work to, including but not limited to MS and Telerik controls.

If you are going to make extensive use of such grids in your applications I would recommend wrapping up this functionality in an HtmlHelper extension that accepts a table of data and the configuration options you need as arguments.

Comment: Thanks, All answers very useful. I have decided for the time being to going with a serverside solution to keep the technology the same. At the a later point I will no doubt replace with JQuery. So to start with I think I will be using the WebGrid or roll my own with inline editting as suggested above. Thanks again. Ed

Answer (score 1):

http://datatables.net/ is a very good jQuery grid. Try it out.

also other options

kendo: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html

jqgrid. http://jqgrid.com/